# Однажды в гостиной, во время какой-то игры, его спросили, как бы он определил себя, и он ответил

Tags: наклонение

*Однажды в гостиной, во время какой-то игры, его спросили, как **бы** он **определил** себя, и он ответил: ... .*

Это ведь сослагательное наклонение, правильно? Немного изменю: ... *его спросили, как он определил бы себя*... 
Не подскажете, семантика глагола *спросить* имеет какое-либо влияние на выбор наклонения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, это сослагательное наклонение. Семантика глагола "сказать" никак не влияет на выбор наклонения.Но не совсем ясно, откуда вы взяли глагол "сказать",если его нет в предложении.

Comment: uyy ошиблась... исправила : ) спасибо!!!

Comment: Даже с поправками, по-моему, ответ остаётся в силе.  "Спросить" не обладает никакими специфическими свойствами.  Сравните, например, с: "его спросили, где он провёл выходной".  Нет никакого сослагательного.